# Does flutter take care of all screen sizes

Tags: flutter

I had an app idea and i want to develop it in either flutter or react native. I chose flutter because I want to learn a new language (Dart) and i know it's still in beta but I don't need to care about a lot of users for at-least 2-3 months since i am gonna learn dart first and then develop it. So my question is

1. Do i have to take care of different screen sizes just like in android or does flutter handle that for me?
2. Do i have to take care of API levels like android or does flutter take care of that? Thank you.

Comment: Just use MediaQuery for device specific layout/functionality.

Comment: MediaQuery can give you a lot more information like the device's current orientation, will the device prefer playing animations at a given point of time,etc..

Comment: I wrote a simple solution based on a third party package here jaycoding.tech/tutorials/guides/… as I don't think MediaQuery is sufficient. You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 6):

> Do i have to take care of different screen sizes just like in android or does flutter handle that for me?

Like Android, Flutter use DP as unit when sizing it's widgets. So pixel density has no effect. 
On the other hand, you still have to make your app "responsive".

Flutter provides a few widgets that help. Such as `AspectRatio`.

> Do i have to take care of API levels like android or does flutter take care of that? Thank you.

Usually, no. There's a plugin for quite a lot of the "low level api".

Sometimes you may need one that hasn't been implemented yet. And you'll need to create it yourself using `Platform Channel`. You can find help [here](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/)

Answer (score 5):

This is a late answer, but I hope it will help someone

- In responsive UI we don’t use hard-coded values for dimension and
  positions.
- Use `MediaQuery` to get the real time size of the window.
- Use `Flexible` and `Expanded` widgets to get a flexible UI that works
  with percentage rather than hard coded values.
- Use `LayoutBuilder` to get the `ConstraintBox` of the parent widget.
- You can get the orientation of the device using `MediaQuery` or
  `OrientationBuilder`.

from this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-responsive-uis-in-flutter-fd450bd59158)

Comment: Checkout the URL you provide, It's invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to adjust the size of the UI according to screen size, you can use.

```
MediaQueryData media = MediaQuery.of(context);
var size = media.size;
```

this will give you screen size of the device.